# Server returned unroutable private IP address in PASV reply

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Trying to set-up FileZilla to connect to my FTP but am having one bugger of a time.  I keep getting this error:
Server returned unroutable private IP address in PASV reply - I have passive enabled in FZ and have tried to set the IP address there as the IP of the PC with FZ Server installed as well as my IP from my ISP but both present the below issue!
Below is the log, can someone more apt to use FileZilla assist me on how to change this?

```
000008)7/11/2014 23:45:59 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000008)7/11/2014 23:45:59 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.45 beta
(000008)7/11/2014 23:45:59 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> 220 Hello and welcome to FileZilla
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:04 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> CLNT https://ftptest.net on behalf of 96.32.136.77
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:04 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> 200 Don't care
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:04 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> USER js
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:04 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> 331 Password required for js
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:05 PM - (not logged in) (213.239.212.239)> PASS ******
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:05 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 230 Logged on
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:05 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> SYST
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:05 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 215 UNIX emulated by FileZilla
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> FEAT
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 211-Features:
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  MDTM
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  REST STREAM
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  SIZE
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  MLST type*;size*;modify*;
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  MLSD
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  UTF8
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  CLNT
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)>  MFMT
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 211 End
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> PWD
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:06 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:07 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> TYPE I
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:07 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 200 Type set to I
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:07 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> PASV
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:07 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,58,202,143)
(000008)7/11/2014 23:46:07 PM - js (213.239.212.239)> disconnected.
```

Comment: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=26748

Comment: @FoggyDay - TY for that site - I didn't know about it.  I created a topic there regarding this issue.  I will mark as solved as soon as I am allowed.

Comment: Suggestion: post an "answer" with your resolution, and mark that answer "accepted".

Comment: FileZilla forum topic this question was moved to: https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=33683